# Why is the cuda version 2x slower than the cpu code?

Tags: c++, cuda

This is a little baffling to me why the cuda code runs about twice as slow as the cpu version.  The cpu code is commented out above the main.  I am just counting all the primes from 0 to (512 * 512 * 512).  The cpu version executed in about 97 seconds whereas the gpu version took 182 seconds. I have an intel i7 running at 4 Ghz and an nvidia GTX 960.  Any ideas why?

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;



__host__ __device__  bool is_prime(uint32_t n)
{
    if(n == 2)
        return true;
    if(n % 2 == 0)
        return false;
    uint32_t sr = sqrtf(n);

    for(uint32_t i = 3; i <= sr; i += 2)
        if(n % i == 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}

__global__ void prime_sum(unsigned int* count)
{
    uint32_t n = (blockIdx.y * gridDim.y + blockIdx.x) * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(is_prime(n))
        atomicAdd(count, 1);
}

int main()
{
    /* CPU VERSION
    time_t start = time(0);
    int pcount = 0;
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < (512 * 512 * 512); i++)
    {
        if(is_prime(i)) pcount++;
    }
    start = time(0) - start;
    std::cout << pcount << "\t" << start << std::endl;
    */

    //CUDA VERSION
    time_t start = time(0);
    unsigned int* sum_d;
    cudaMalloc(&sum_d, sizeof(unsigned int));
    cudaMemset(sum_d, 0, sizeof(unsigned int));

    prime_sum<<< dim3(512, 512), 512 >>>(sum_d);

    unsigned int sum = 0;
    cudaMemcpy(&sum, sum_d, sizeof(unsigned int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    start = time(0) - start;
    std::cout << sum << "\t" << start << std::endl;
    cudaFree(sum_d);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is one idea.  The efficiency of the is_prime function comes from being able to exit quickly most of the time because most numbers will be divisible by 2 or lower numbers so when executed in serial most of the time the loop exits fast.  However due to warps each group of 32 threads must wait for the worst to finish.  Also I am including evens so half the threads will be eliminated by the first if.

Comment: SO is not a code review site. Do you have a _specific_ problem? Otherwise try code review, but first read their FAQs.

Comment: My question is why is the code slower?

Comment: Are you compiling with -G ?  When I run your code on a Quadro5000/Xeon X5560, the GPU is 4x faster than the CPU.

Comment: You really would want to eliminate the even numbers right off the bat by assigning thread `i` to integer `i*2+3`.

Comment: Yes but even still I am just wondering why it is slower than the cpu code.  I could make the same optimization for the cpu.  Then again the cpu gets rid of the evens on the second if whereas the evens here suck up half the warp.

Comment: Why do you think something as naïve as this integer algorithm should automatically be faster on a GPU?

Comment: Because it breaks down really well into parallel execution.

Comment: The -G option works really well.  I didn't know that.  I am used to using gcc where debugger output does not affect the optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, GPUs generally have good floating point computing power but not integer computing power, and modular (and division) operation is very slow.

Second, global atmoic operations are slow before Kelper architecture, but you have a GTX 960, so I think it's not the problem.

Third, for CPU version, each integer can exit the loop right after it is not a prime. However for GPU, an integer must wait until all of its 32 neighbor threads exit. In your code, the even threads exit right after they enter the kernel but they must wait until the odd threads finish their loop.

BTW, why do you use <<< dim3(512,512), 512>>>? I think 1D work dimension <<<512*512,512>>> is fairly enough.

Comment: I chose 512 * 512 so I could handle larger datasets.  Originally I had it at <<< dim3(1024,1024), 1024>>>  but this took forever.

Comment: I actually just imporved my occupancy by doing this.  prime_sum<<< dim3(512, 256), 1024 >>>(sum_d); so that I am using all 1024 threads per block.

Comment: Atomic instructions are faster in Kepler and Maxwell, but can still be an performance issue, especially if they all use the same address. Especially for the blocks at the beginning where primes are still very common, it might be beneficial to count primes per block first (e.g.: using atomic adds in shared memory or using reduction) and then use only a single atomic add at the end of the block.